# How can i test in react for copy and paste events

Tags: reactjs, testing

I have copy button in my component. I want to test firstly copy and after paste somewhere. How can i do this test ?

```
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

import React from "react";
import App from "./App";

describe("is copied ?", () => {


  test("try copy", () => {

    render(<App />);

    const copyBtn = screen.getAllByText("Click to copy emoji");
    const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText("search emoji");

    userEvent.click(copyBtn[0]);

    userEvent.paste(input, window.ClipboardItem);

    expect(input).toHaveValue();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use React Testing Library, try to think about what users will see or have feedback when some action happens.
So, in your case, when the user clicks on the copy button, what should happen? Should the user see something?

When they paste the value what was supposed to happen?

In your test, maybe you can get the emoji and test if the value in the input is equal to the first emoji.

Comment: When the user clicks on the copy button, the copying process takes place and can paste. I want to do this in react-test. but I don't know how to do the copy and paste events.